# asp.net Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int using session

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, session

I want to fill the GridView reading Session variable Id but I got error that to converting data type as like `{"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'finalProject.User' to data type int."}` but I haven't nvarchar value in my Database table it's already int. How to I fix it?
**finalProject.User**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

**User object**

```
User u = new User();
                u.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]);
                u.name = dr["name"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["name"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                u.surname = dr["surname"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["surname"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                u.email = dr["email"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["email"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                Session["user"] = u;
```

**My codes**

```
public partial class MyConferences : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    internal User user;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        object user = Session["user"];

        if(user != null)
        {
            user = Session["user"] as User;
        }           

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;

        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "select Conferences.conferenceName , Conferences.conferenceDate , Conferences.conferencePlace , Conferences.category from Conferences inner join Users on Conferences.fk_Users = Users.Id where Users.Id = @UserId";

            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);

                SqlParameter prm = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", user.ToString());

                if(user == null)
                {
                    prm.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

**Error**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

mark_h is right you are passing `string` value to `int` but you also dont know how to pass the `id`. It would be better if you give proper type instead of `object`.

```
object user = Session["user"] as User;
```

will be

```
User user = Session["user"] as User;
```

and

```
SqlParameter prm = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", user.Id);
```

Comment: can you provide the code of the page where you created the gridview

Comment: or just add `GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;`  in the code

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to pass a string as an integer;

```
            SqlParameter prm = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", user.ToString());
```

UserId is an integer but user.ToString() is a string. Did you mean to use this as your parameter instead?

```
Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"])
```

Comment: When I remove the ToString() methods now I got error that is "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code" and "No mapping exists from object type to a known managed provider native type "

Comment: Replace user.ToString() with Convert.TOInt32(Session["UserId"]) and see if that works. You need to pass an integer, or you could try user.Id instead of user.ToString()

Comment: It works faultlessly but I didn't get the result I want. Nothing happened . It should be fiil in the gridview I dont understand why?

Comment: I found 2 errors in gridview that " SelectedDataKey = 'GridView1.SelectedDataKey' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' " and " SelectedValue = 'GridView1.SelectedValue' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' "

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are passing a wrong value "user.ToString()" rather "Session["UserId"]". The user is an object and userId looks like a single id value. Dont forget to convert before sending value.